# ERROR: Could not find 'which' command, make sure it's available first before continuing installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, deployment, centos

I'm trying to deploy rails application in Cent-OS. When I run `curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` to setup ruby environment.
I got the following output

```
[root@186-aven-vps marketeurepo]# curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    581      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   580
100 22721  100 22721    0     0  35092      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 35092

ERROR: Could not find 'which' command, make sure it's available first before continuing installation.
```

I'm using Mac OS X on local machine and I'm new to this.Any suggestion will be appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: `which` should be in `/usr/bin/` as it is on my Mac 10.10.5. Somehow this directory is not in your `$PATH`. You should edit your `~/.bash_profile` and add the appropriate directory to PATH

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it by running this command:

```
$ yum install which
```